# Combine CASE expression in JOIN Clause involving different comparison operators

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case, inner-join

I have two SELECT statements and want to combine them into one JOIN statement based on the input param: @UseFirstOne = true.
If @UseFirstOne is true then we join on the first condition and if false, then we join on the second condition.

1.

```
    JOIN X.[Employee] emp 
     ON emp.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
     AND emp.BirthYear = @BirthYearFromParam
```

2. 

```
    JOIN X.[Employee] emp 
     ON emp.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
     AND emp.BirthYear < @CurrentYear OR (emp.BirthYear = @CurrentYear AND emp.BirthMonth < @CurrentMonth)
```

How can I combine them into one JOIN statement?

Comment: Those clauses look like they should be in the `WHERE`, not the `ON`; there's no relational clauses there and it's not a `LEFT JOIN`. Though with conditional `AND`/`OR` clauses you'll probably also want to add `RECOMPILE` to your `OPTION` clause.

Comment: In what circumstances would an Employee not have a BirthYear before current year?

Comment: More the point: why isn't there just one `DateOfBirth` column? Then you can do `AND @UseFirstOne = 0 OR emp.DateOfBirth >= DATEFROMPARTS(@BirthYearFromParam, 1, 1)`

Comment: @Utsab: Do you maintain **@UseFirstOne** just to reflect whether or not **@BirthYearFromParam** is available? If **@BirthYearFromParam** was not available - would it be `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think algebraically, and use parenthesis to enforce the logic order you want. Consider:

```
DECLARE @UseFirstOne BIT = 0, @BirthYearFromParam INT = 2000

SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE 
    (
        DATEPART(YEAR,BirthDate) = @BirthYearFromParam 
        AND @UseFirstOne = 1
    )
    OR 
    (
        (
            DATEPART(YEAR,BirthDate) < DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())
            OR
            (
                DATEPART(YEAR,BirthDate) =  DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())
                AND DATEPART(MONTH,BirthDate) < DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())
            )
        )
        AND @UseFirstOne = 0
    )
```

Comment: The.OP doesn't appear to have a `BirthDate` column, according to their question, they have separate columns for the parts. Though even if they do have such a column, these clauses would not be SARGable so would be unable to use any indexes.

Comment: They don't, they appear to be using just a year, but without DDL/DML for their table I resorted to using an existing one, since the columns themselves are not important to answering the question, just the structure of the logic.

Comment: @ThomA - I doubt sargability is a concern as both queries have `EmployeeId = @EmployeeId` which I assume will narrow things down to a single row against an Employee table. So this is just a residual predicate on one row

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional logic with the correct use of parenthesis (brackets)

```
AND ((
  @UseFirstOne = 1
  AND emp.BirthYear = @BirthYearFromParam
) OR (
  @UseFirstOne = 0
  AND (
    emp.BirthYear < @CurrentYear
    OR (
      emp.BirthYear = @CurrentYear
      AND emp.BirthMonth < @CurrentMonth
  ))
))
```